# restoring original order of a vector/matrix in r

Tags: r, sorting

so i had a vector

```
> A<-c(19:30,1:5,6,100:80)
```

then i used

```
> A<-sort(A,index.return=T)
> valueA<-A$x
> indexA<-A$ix
```

to sort the vector and get a vector stating the values.  i then performed some arithmetic on valueA that required it be sorted first and now i want to put the new values in the order that A was originally in (which is saved in the vector indexA).

is this a thing?  sort of a "restore" or "un-sort" or whatever?  i've tried looking around and it seems there are things that are close, but either not right or i'm not understanding.

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the `base` function `order`.

```
ord <- order(A)
A <- A[ord] #same as sort(A)
#do stuff, then revert
A <- A[order(ord)]
```

Comment: I've spent a bit coming up with `-1 * ord + max(ord) + 1` and now I feel pretty dumb. Thanks m)